# placing log files in different folders based on month and day

Tags: java, shell, unix

This is a homework question.
I have a shell script in which i am creating a folder structure .Then i am giving a call to java program where i am extracting data from a table writing it into the file and want to place the file to that folder. The folder structure changes everyday.
as let suppose the folder structure like Logs/Month/day and i am creating that everyday.
How can i place the data file to the particular folder.

Ex.  I have a_20131216.log to be placed in logs/12/16
            a_20131215.log to be placed in logs/12/15

Comment: by creating File to that directory path - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java/3634906#3634906 similar to this

Comment: jigar thanks for  your reply . i am creating folder through script. how can i copy the file created to that folder location. that also everyday changing location.

Comment: you could use mv (move) or cp (copy) command in bash script to move / copy file or in java you can generate same directory path and move/copy it to that location Directly using `FileUtils` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: ok will try to use the apache FileUtils. Thanks Jigar

Comment: when you get it answered please answer it by yourself and accept it for other's reference

Answer (score 1):

Look at

- the `date` command to create the directory name.
- the `-p` option to `mkdir`