# Saving File using java GUI in pc hard disk

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

This is a code for Opening a file using `JFileChooser` --->

```
package fileStreamObjectSerialization;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FileDemonstrationJFileChooser extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea outputArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    public FileDemonstrationJFileChooser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super("Testing class file");
        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);

        analyzePath();

        int x = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(outputArea);
                                        // How can i save the file in my hard disk
    }

    private File getFileOrDirectory() {

        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        File fileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        if ((fileName == null) || (fileName.getName().equals(""))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid name", "Invalid name",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    private void analyzePath() {
        File name = getFileOrDirectory();
        if (name.exists()) {
            outputArea.setText(String.format(
                    "%s%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s", name
                            .getName(), " exists", (name.isFile() ? "is a file"
                            : "is not a file"),
                    (name.isDirectory() ? "is a directory"
                            : "is not a directory"),
                    (name.isAbsolute() ? "is absolute path"
                            : "is not absolute path"), "Last modified: ", name
                            .lastModified(), "Length: ", name.length(),
                    "Path: ", name.getPath(), "Absolute path: ", name
                            .getAbsolutePath(), "Parent: ", name.getParent()));

            if (name.isDirectory()) {
                String[] directory = name.list();
                outputArea.append("\n\nDirectory contents:\n");

                for (String directoryName : directory) {
                    outputArea.append(directoryName + "\n");
                }
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, name + " does not exist.",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
}
```

Now my question is How Can i save the file in my hard disk on clicking the SAVE button on the save dialog ??

Comment: Use the same logic for your open dialog, but use `showSaveDialog` instead.  The resulting `File` need to exist, you can use `File#getParentFile#mkdirs` to make the directories if they don't exist, demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059085/how-can-i-create-a-file-in-the-current-users-home-directory-using-java/21059316#21059316). You can then write to the file in any number of ways, depending on what you want to save, for example, you could use [`JTextArea#write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer))

Comment: See [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details