# how to create folder at perticular path using java code

Tags: java, file-io

I want to create a folder at a particular path (location which is given by user) using java code.

```
File dir = new File("Hermatic");
dir.mkdir();
```

This code create 'hermatic' folder but i want to set path so that folder create at given location.

Comment: Start by not tag spamming.

Comment: Could you please clean up your tags I don't see what ajax has to do with this for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class Main {
    public static void createFolder(String path) throws Exception {
        File dir = new File(path);
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = args[0]; //takes the first argument from the command line
        createFolder(path);
    }
}
```

So running your application with

```
java -jar myapp.jar /home/me/folder
```

would create the folder with the path **/home/me/folder**

Answer (score 0):

```
String location = "C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\";
File file = new File(location + "filename.txt");
```