# Java where to put plenty of files written by user and read by program

Tags: java

I'm creating a video-game and I would like to let the player create his own level (stored as .txt file).

I read that the most common solution was to put them in the user home directory using `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

The problem is that the player may create a lot of levels (and thus a lot of files) and that I will soon be disordered.

Is there a way to create a folder with my game and to store those files into it? If so, how can I access them for read and write?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java: create a directory under user.home and put all your files in there.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use something like this

`File targetFolder = new File("targetPath");
targetFolder.mkdir();`

Code above will create new folder, so you can store files in this folder.