# Unable to create a file path in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to save my file into a perticular directory. but i get the below Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\News\nxis\NewFiles\I0cbf74105a2d11e5b730aca98fc673fd.nxi (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.NXI.CreateNxi.createFiles(CreateNxi.java:49)
    at org.NXI.GetInput.main(GetInput.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\News\nxis\NewFiles\I0cbf74105a2d11e5b730aca98fc673fd.nxi (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
---------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\News\nxis\NewFiles\I0cbf74105a2d11e5b730aca98fc673fd.nxi (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.NXI.CreateNxi.createFiles(CreateNxi.java:49)
    at org.NXI.GetInput.main(GetInput.java:24)
```

Here the path that is available in real is

```
    String output = "D:\\News\\nxis\\" + replaceGuid + ".nxi";
```

But i'm trying to add a new folder inside it. I'm using the below command

```
    String output = "D:\\News\\nxis\\New Folder" + replaceGuid + ".nxi";
```

When i run my program with the second step. It throws me an error. please let me know how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634906/4088809

Comment: You should use File.separator (will select needed separator automatically depending on your OS) and be aware of your directory structure before opening the file to prevent such issues.

Comment: You need to first check if the directory with the path specified exists or not, If not, you need to create it first then only you can create a file in that directory.

Comment: `"D:\\News\\nxis\\NewFile\\"` seems to be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will fix your problem:

```
new File(output).mkdir();
```

mkdir() creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

Comment: `new File(output).getParentFile().mkdirs();` or `mkdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that D:\News\nxis\ directory path is existing if not you have to create it.