# How to create a folder in Windows by a Java Program?

Tags: java, windows, directory

I would like to write a Java Programm which should be able to create a Folder in Windows, but the Client should be a able to decide on the Name of the Folder. How can I do that?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: with an input in the type of `String` and by using the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class

Answer (score 0):

A small google search would have given you the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java). If you want to name it a specific way, just grab the name from a JTextField or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a File object and use mkdir() to create a new folder.

```
File folder;
folder = new File("path/to/new/folder");
folder.mkdir();
```

Obviously you will need to check if the folder already exists and you will need to use an inputted string for the name of the folder.