# Java - Create an empty directory

Tags: java, directory, create-directory

I want to create a new directory.
If it doesn't exist - create it.
if it exists - I want to "reset"/"truncate" the directory. 
In other words, **I want to get an empty directory**

My problems are -

1. I read that to check an existence of a directory to decide whether
   or not to create it is a bad practise, so I can't determine what should I do next.
   You can read the explanation about why it is a bad practise   in [How to create a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java)
2. I can iterate over all the files and delete them, but I'm looking for a more elegant approach.

Comment: Re 1.: do you access the directory concurrently or not (if you do I don't think there is an atomic way of emptying a directory)? Re 2., that's what is going to happen under the hood anyway.

Comment: Have a look at commons-io. E.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File)

Comment: One thing is certain: do not use `File`. Read the other answers to the question there. They have much information.

Comment: I think that I have everything  I need in Class FileUtils.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Using some java 8 pattern you have efficiency around directory cleaning and creating ,

```
File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists())
    {

        file.mkdir();
    }
    else
    {            
        Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/test/ABC/"))
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .forEach(File::delete);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its true that it is a bad practice. As **mkdir** fails to create directory if same directory name exist. So there is no need of double checking whether a directory with same name exist or not. That is why it is bad practice to check before calling *mkdir*.

Simple way you can do is to first check if directory exist or not. if so then *delete* it and call **mkdir**

You can look into the [JDK Bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=1241581). Community members mentioned it as a bug.

Comment: @paz reingold If the answer is helpfully please accept the answer and vote it up.