# Change directory in Unix with Java

Tags: java, unix, runtime.exec

I am trying to change current working directory in unix using Java , but it's not working

Here is my sample:

1. The current working directory is `/temp/input`
2. I want to change the directory to `/test/output`
3. And create new folder using `mkdir`

```java
String[] commands = new String [] {"bash", "-c", "mkdir temp"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands,null,new File("/test1/output"));
```

Comment: You can use java capability to create a folder. See answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java. You can just pass your path as a parameter

Comment: If all you're after is file/directory manipulation, I'd advise you to check the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) APIs instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply, agree, but it will not work in case of other unix commands such as tar, cp etc. Here am facing issue while changing directory.