# Ad-hoc directory creation

Tags: java, filewriter

In the code below ,I am writing a file named `employee_status_downloader_unixtimestamp.csv` in an already created directory on RHEL server as shown in this line of code below:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/srv/file_users/JACK/employee_status_downloader_"+unixTimestamp+".csv");
```

So, I manually created a folder named `JACK` and then specified the above path so that the files related to the `userName` `JACK` are inside `JACK` folder.

Since the `userName` can be different and I am already getting the `userName` in my method `sendMessage` as shown below from this line of code `String userName = parts[1].trim();`, I am wondering if I could make use of this 
    to create a directory based on the `userName`?

So, I am not using `System.getProperty("user.name");` here since I am already getting `userName` in my method above which I believe is enough for creating an ad-hoc directory.

After looking online , I found that people are [suggesting here(Bozho's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java) to do something like this :

`File fl = new File("/path/directory").mkdirs();` where directory is the name of the directory I want to create/exist. But since I am using `FileWriter` above,  I am wondering how should I go about using both so that 
I could also create a directory if it doesn't exist and then write a file in the directory.

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

        String[] parts = msg.split("#");
        String requestID = parts[0].trim();
        String userName = parts[1].trim();
        String applicationName = parts[2].trim();

        logger.info("Request ID " + requestID);
        logger.info("User Name " + userName);
        logger.info("Application Name " + applicationName);



        try {


            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/srv/file_users/JACK/employee_status_downloader_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");

            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw);

            writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
            writer.close();
            fw.close();


        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        } finally {


        }



    }
    long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure the folder exists, change code to:

```
File dir = new File("/srv/file_users/", userName);
dir.mkdirs();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(dir, "/employee_status_downloader_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv"));
```

Better yet, use the newer NIO methods and use try-with-resources to ensure file is closed correctly.

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/file_users", userName);
Files.createDirectories(dir);

Path file = dir.resolve("employee_status_downloader_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(file))) {
    writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The newer NIO file options works fine for me. Hence using it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do with a path in a String, you can do in a parameterized way by parameterizing the String.  You have this:

```
String userName = parts[1].trim();
...
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/srv/file_users/JACK/employee_status_downloader_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
```

so you could do this:

```
String userName = parts[1].trim();
...
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/srv/file_users/" + userName + "/employee_status_downloader_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to what you suggested doesn't create a new directory (in case it doesn't exist).