# Intellij plugin make package and main class

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have made a Project Wizard in the intellij plugin im making, now what I want to do at the end of that is make it generate the src/main/java, or src/main/kotlin, depending on the data provided in the project wizard ive made. I also want it to make this as a gradle project. If anyone knows how to do this that would be much appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you want to IDE recognize the project as a gradle project you must generate gradle files(build.gradle, settings.gradle and etc) based on [this doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html). and after generating finished you must call sync gradle with this line of code inside your ide-plugin.

```
ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(
        project,
        ProjectSystemId("GRADLE"),
        "YOUR_PROJECT_PATH",
        false,
        ProgressExecutionMode.IN_BACKGROUND_ASYNC
)
```

Hope this help

Comment: How do I generate the src/main/java folders and whatnot?

Comment: It's simple just get the project path from `Project` class and crate folder with java or kotlin File API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java

Comment: Oh, was just wondering if there was a fancy way to do that with the intellij api, how do i mark it as the src dir and whatnot?